# How to find the most appropriate date between overlapping date periods in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, date-range

I`w got an 2 tables with such data:

Table 1

| id | s_id | s_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 33 | 2021-03-05 10:36:59 |
| 2 | 33 | 2021-03-06 10:36:59 |
| 3 | 33 | 2021-03-09 10:36:59 |
| 4 | 33 | 2021-03-10 13:36:59 |
| 5 | 33 | 2021-03-11 12:36:59 |
| 6 | 33 | 2021-03-12 09:00:59 |
| 7 | 33 | 2021-03-13 13:36:59 |
| 8 | 33 | 2021-03-14 18:00:00 |
| 9 | 33 | 2021-03-15 18:00:00 |
| 10 | 33 | 2021-03-16 13:00:00 |
| 11 | 33 | 2021-03-17 18:00:00 |
| 12 | 33 | 2021-03-18 14:00:00 |
| 13 | 33 | 2021-04-01 18:00:00 |
| 14 | 33 | 2021-05-02 14:00:00 |

Table 2

| id | s_id | amount | date_from | date_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 33 | 100 | 2012-03-12 00:00:00 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 33 | 200 | 2018-03-12 00:00:09 | 2021-02-28 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 33 | 300 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | 2021-03-31 00:00:00 |
| 4 | 33 | 400 | 2021-03-07 00:00:00 | 2021-03-12 00:00:00 |

How to select row with appropriate id where s_date between date_from and date_to most close to date_from\date_to range?
In my case most appropriate rows must be:

| id | s_id | s_date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 33 | 2021-03-05 10:36:59 | 300 |
| 2 | 33 | 2021-03-06 10:36:59 | 300 |
| 3 | 33 | 2021-03-09 10:36:59 | 400 |
| 4 | 33 | 2021-03-10 13:36:59 | 400 |
| 5 | 33 | 2021-03-11 12:36:59 | 400 |
| 6 | 33 | 2021-03-12 09:00:59 | 400 |
| 7 | 33 | 2021-03-13 13:36:59 | 300 |
| 8 | 33 | 2021-03-14 18:00:00 | 300 |
| 9 | 33 | 2021-03-15 18:00:00 | 300 |
| 10 | 33 | 2021-03-16 13:00:00 | 300 |
| 11 | 33 | 2021-03-17 18:00:00 | 300 |
| 12 | 33 | 2021-03-18 14:00:00 | 300 |
| 13 | 33 | 2021-04-01 18:00:00 | 100 |
| 14 | 33 | 2021-05-02 14:00:00 | 100 |

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the mid date for each pair of `date_from` and `date_to` with:

```
(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_from) + UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_to)) / 2
```

Then find the absolute difference from `s_date` and sort by that:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
ORDER BY ABS(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(s_date) - ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_from) + UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_to)) / 2))
```

You can apply `LIMIT 2` to get the 2 most *appropriate* `id`s.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d44782fc90c4ad1d0593e166f21755b8).

Comment: In fact can be as many rows as many days in month or even unlimited if s_date will call between filter range.

Comment: @Doom I don't understand your comment. All I have seen is the sample data you posted. So my query works for this sample data. It returns the rows ordered in such a way that s_dates closer to the mid of each range are at the top. You can filter the query any way you want.

Comment: It seems i not very correct ask question. Your code work great. Thx. I ask another way. Thx again.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to filter for the rows using date comparisons?  For your examples:

```
select t.*
from t
where s_date >= date_from and s.date < date_to;
```

Comment: In this case will select more than one row for s_id, for s_id 33 it will be id 3 and 4, they both in range.